# How do I change column headers on a return value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return everything in my table but I want to change the column headings ONLY when it gets returned.

```
SELECT * FROM d_cds
```

That returns all the values from the table under the original column headings. How would I display them with different headings?

Comment: Why can't you explictly list the columns giving each an alias?

Comment: I asked that and was informed he wanted them shown in a different format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT yourColumn as NameYouWant FROM d_cds
```