# Return all rows and columns in SQL while changing heading in one column

Tags: sql, database

Here's the full question and the database that I'm working with.

"What command would you use to return all rows and columns, with the ProductName column heading appearing as “Name”?"

Database: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298345/how-do-i-change-column-headers-on-a-return-value)

I found a similar solution from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298345/how-do-i-change-column-headers-on-a-return-value), ***SELECT ProductName as Name FROM Products*** but I only had the ProductName column return instead of the whole table.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is explicitly listing the columns with any one you want to rename.

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName as [Name], SupplierID, CategoryID, Unit, Price FROM [Products]
```

UPDATE: Based on jarlh's comment, the more precise query should be like:

```
SELECT "ProductID", "ProductName" as [Name], "SupplierID", "CategoryID", "Unit", "Price" FROM [Products]
```

Or if it's SQL Server with default settings, the query can also be written like:

```
SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName] as [Name], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [Unit], [Price] FROM [Products]
```

The update is mainly for eliminate the possible effects from SQL collation.

Comment: No dbms is specified in question, so ANSI SQL is assumed, so please use double quotes for delimited identifiers. (Doesn't that work with MS SQL Server too these days?)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

`SELECT ProductName as Name, Products.* FROM Products` however you will get 2 copies of the ProductName column, one named `Name` (the aliased column) and one named `ProductName` (the original column).

The alternative is to list out each column such as 
`SELECT ProductName as Name, ProductCategory, ProductSubcategory FROM Products.* FROM Products`